# HTML Line between circles

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

But this is what I've managed to do.

[image]

Could you please help me to achieve desired result?

**UPDATE:**

Problem goes away if I remove bootstrap.css dependency. How can I make it work with bootstrap?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dashadasha/pen/JYjaXb) (add bootstrap.css in the settings to see an issue)

```css
.time-slice {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.time-slice > * {
  padding: 20px;
}

.circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;

  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 32px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #1A87B9;
}

.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
}

.circle-wrap > .circle {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
}

.date-time {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 60px;
}

.date,
.time {
  max-width: 90px;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.point-title {
  border-left: 2px solid #1A87B9;
}
```

```html
<div id="ticketDetails">
    <h1>Details</h1>


    <div class="time-slice row">
        <div class="date-time">
            <p class="time">10h 30min</p>
            <p class="date">&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrap">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="point-title">
        <span>
          <b>Amsterdam (Schiphol)</b>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="time-slice row">
        <div class="date-time">
            <p class="date">Fri 28 Aug</p>
            <p class="time">20:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-wrap">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="point-title">
        <span>
          <b>Manchester (MAN)</b>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The problem is in `* {box-sizing: border-box}` used by Bootstrap. Simply either set default `box-sizing: content-box` to `.circle` ([fixed demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/qOBMQp?editors=110)) or take this property setting of the BS into account when you size/align your stuff.

Comment: Works! Could you please post it as an answer so I could accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `* {box-sizing: border-box}` used by Bootstrap. Simply either set default `box-sizing: content-box` for `.circle` ([fixed codepen demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/qOBMQp?editors=110)) or take this property setting of the BS into account when you size/align your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  > .circle {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
  }
}
```

to

```
.circle-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  & > .circle {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm! It looks fine when I run a code snippet, but still shifted in when I integrate it with my HTML. What could be a potential reason?

Comment: **UPDATE:** 
Problem goes away if I remove bootstrap.css dependency. How can I make it work with bootstrap?

Comment: Try to look at it with firebug (firefox extension). So you can disable single css statements and you will see the changes instantly.

Comment: @HotPizzaBox, I was trying to disable property by property on firebug but nothing changes. I've prepared CodePen, if you add bootstrap.css you can  try to play with it. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, these are identical Less snippets (`a { > b ...` is equal to `a { & > b ...`), so this change can't fix anything.